# Calculating the difference of entry values in pd.DataFrame comparing multiple indices

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I'd like to insert the difference of every two differences of the energy values out of a `pd.DataFrame` containing data of multiple bases (A, C, G, T, U<sup>1</sup> and U<sup>2</sup>) for every base in every environment and so on. I thought of something like fhe following. I thought of iterating through the whole data frame, but it didn't work and is also definitely not how `pd.DataFrame`s are intended to be used.
E. g., I'd like having the difference in charge of base A in pbs between its "neutral" and its "positive" value expanding the princple for every base, environment and maybe more criteria, which could be added in future.

Although I heard of `pandas.MultiIndex`, I didn't have much experience with it, but this looks like a possible solution to me, isn't it?

```py
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import os

with open (os.path.join (os.environ ['HOME'], 'data.csv'), 'r') as f :
    df = pd.read_csv (f, index_col = 0, header = 0, thousands = None, decimal = '.')

df = df.loc [df ['base'].isin (['A', 'C', 'G', 'U'])]

# one way I tried
pos = df.loc [df ['charge'] == 'pos']
neg = df.loc [df ['charge'] == 'neg']
neu = df.loc [df ['charge'] == 'neu']

df.loc [df ['charge'] == 'neg', 'difference'] = neg ['energy'] - neu ['energy']
df.loc [df ['charge'] == 'pos', 'difference'] = pos ['energy'] - neu ['energy']

# another way I tried
for posneg in ['pos', 'neg'] :
    df.loc [df ['charge'] == posneg, 'difference'] = lit.query ("(charge == 'neu') - (charge == '@posneg')")
```

**~/data.csv**:

```
,environment,base,charge,energy,type
0,pbs,A,neg,0.34835,1
1,pbs,C,neg,0.40194,2
2,pbs,G,neg,0.34959,1
3,pbs,T,neg,0.40738,2
4,pbs,U1,neg,0.34904,2
5,pbs,U2,neg,0.40016,2
6,pbs,A,neu,0.40151,3
7,pbs,C,neu,0.34494,3
8,pbs,G,neu,0.40193,3
9,pbs,T,neu,0.34458,3
10,pbs,U1,neu,0.34646,3
11,pbs,U2,neu,0.40871,3
12,pbs,A,pos,0.34047,2
13,pbs,C,pos,0.40157,2
14,pbs,G,pos,0.34232,2
15,pbs,T,pos,0.40854,2
16,pbs,U1,pos,0.34611,2
17,pbs,U2,pos,0.34414,2
18,polymeric,A,neg,0.28333,2
19,polymeric,C,neg,0.46908,3
20,polymeric,G,neg,0.33224,3
21,polymeric,T,neg,0.35825,1
22,polymeric,U1,neg,0.33033,3
23,polymeric,U2,neg,0.39167,3
24,polymeric,A,neu,0.36964,2
25,polymeric,C,neu,0.33979,2
26,polymeric,G,neu,0.41815,3
27,polymeric,T,neu,0.30786,2
28,polymeric,U1,neu,0.40727,1
29,polymeric,U2,neu,0.36719,3
30,polymeric,A,pos,0.38173,1
31,polymeric,C,pos,0.35060,3
32,polymeric,G,pos,0.37617,1
33,polymeric,T,pos,0.44172,2
34,polymeric,U1,pos,0.31267,3
35,polymeric,U2,pos,0.34478,2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the first subtraction is reflected in the code, as it was unclear how many calculations there were. I think it's easy to follow this format.

Process flow:

1. data frame transformation
2. Eliminate multiple indexes.
3. change the column name
4. calculation A, calculation B

```
# Extract the condition
df = df.loc[df['base'].isin (['A','C','G','U'])]
# long to wide
df = df.set_index(['environment','base','charge']).unstack()
# Eliminate multi-indexing
df.columns = df.columns.droplevel()
# Eliminate indexing
df = df.rename_axis(columns=None).reset_index()
# rename columns
df.columns = ['environment','base','neg','neu','pos','neg_type','neu_type','pos_type']
df['neg-neu'] = df['neg']-df['neu']
df['pos-neu'] = df['pos']-df['neu']
df
    environment base    neg neu pos neg_type    neu_type    pos_type    neg-neu pos-neu
0   pbs A   0.34835 0.40151 0.34047 1   3   2   -0.05316    -0.06104
1   pbs C   0.40194 0.34494 0.40157 2   3   2   0.05700 0.05663
2   pbs G   0.34959 0.40193 0.34232 1   3   2   -0.05234    -0.05961
3   polymeric   A   0.28333 0.36964 0.38173 2   2   1   -0.08631    0.01209
4   polymeric   C   0.46908 0.33979 0.35060 3   2   3   0.12929 0.01081
5   polymeric   G   0.33224 0.41815 0.37617 3   3   1   -0.08591    -0.04198
```

Comment: I get a `ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 8 elements, new values have 11 elements` by the line `df.columns = [list]` (5th line). I tried your solution with recreating `~/data.csv` and putting it in a `mwe.py` getting the same error. The columns `'neg_idx','neu_idx','pos_idx'` aren't present in `df` at the end, but does this matter?

Comment: I'd also appreciate if you could explain the single steps (what happens in which one and why is it needed here) and why you chose this possibility.

Comment: I ran it again to check. As you pointed out, that column is not needed. Fixed the code and added comments.